# How to remove specific character from wordpress URL

Tags: wordpress

How to remove specific character from wordpress URL as we have installed wordpress in blog  folder and using nginx server with PHP 7

Example : www.vkwins.com/blog/press/vinay
we need to remove blog from URL it should be: www.vkwins.com/press/vinay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change in wp-includes/link-template.php

in function get_permalink

```
if ($post->post_type == 'page') return get_page_link($post, $leavename, $sample);
elseif ( $post->post_type == 'attachment' )
    return get_attachment_link( $post, $leavename );
elseif (in_array($post->post_type, get_post_types(array('_builtin' => false)))) {
    if ($post->post_type == 'press') {
        return str_replace('/blog', '', get_post_permalink($post, $leavename, $sample));
    } else {
        return get_post_permalink($post, $leavename, $sample);
    }
}
```

Also, you have to make change for url rewriting, so that new url will work as required

```
location /press {
    root   /html/www/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove your post type, then you can use this code..

Change post type **service** with your post type and paste it in `functions.php`

```
function na_remove_slug( $post_link, $post, $leavename ) {

    if ( 'service' != $post->post_type || 'publish' != $post->post_status ) {
        return $post_link;
    }

    $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link );

    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'na_remove_slug', 10, 3 );

/*====================================================
remove of code of custom post type...
======================================================*/

function na_parse_request( $query ) {

    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() || 2 != count( $query->query ) || ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! empty( $query->query['name'] ) ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'service', 'page' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'na_parse_request' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally URL rewriting being done by adding url rewriting rules in .htaccess file. Wordpress have a builtin functionality name Permalink to do it.

In Wordpress admin go to Settings → Permalinks panel (Options → Permalinks before WordPress 2.5), you can choose one of the "common" structures or enter your own in the "Custom structure" field using the structure tags for defining your choose of URL. 
or your can try [this](https://www.webhostinghero.com/remove-category-from-wp-permalinks/)

Comment: then u can try Wp admin panel permalinks

Comment: wp admin permalink is not working without adding location in ngnix.conf file